# How-to display a .gif as background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, gif

I have a javascript "loading" function like this:

```
function splashScreen() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode("some text"));
    div.style.position = "fixed";
    div.style.width = "100%";
    div.style.height = "100%";
    div.style.left = "0";
    div.style.top = "0";
    div.style.zIndex = "1000";
    div.style.background = "white url('img/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat center";
    div.style.fontSize = "x-large";
    div.style.textAlign = "center";
    div.style.lineHeight = "3em";
    div.style.opacity = "0.75";
    div.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=75)"; // fix ie
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    return true;
}
```

I use this function in the form action (`onsubmit="return splashScreen()"`) to show a "rotating logo" while the next page load...
The problem is in that "img/loading.gif" and safari (on winXP): in ff and ie I have no problems, and I clearly see the animated gif. In safari I can't see it.
If I change the image with a (obviously static) png the image appears...
Am I doing something wrong? What's the problem with safari?

Comment: There are known bug reports about safari and animated gifs. The gifs freeze - in certain cases even the browser freezes - I experienced this on pages that load large amounts of animated gifs.

Comment: Incidentally please don't use `getAttribute`/`setAttribute` on HTML documents. There are serious bugs in it in IE6-7, which will make it fail for the `style` attribute and others. It is both more reliable and more readable to use the DOM Level 2 HTML and CSS properties: `div.style.textAlign= 'center';` et al. Also, `document.body` is preferable to the `getElementsByTagName` call.

Comment: tanks @bobince, I changed the source following your advices...

unfortunately, the problem remanins :\

Answer (score 0):

Safari doesn't handle animated background well enough. I've seen a bug report about that somewhere.

Why don't you just use an image instead of a background?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not personally familiar with this issue, but I was able to find a handful of similar bug reports online.  What else are you doing on this page?  Are you keeping focus on the page when you experience this issue?  Apparently the handling of animated GIFs is pretty complicated:

http://webkit.org/blog/96/background-music/
http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2004/12/animated_gifs_u.html
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7320

Particularly relevant snippet from that first link:

> In both Safari 2 and WebKit nightlies, GIFs don’t animate unless they are being painted somewhere. If an animated GIF becomes invisible, then the animation will pause and no CPU will be consumed by the animation. Therefore all animated images in a background tab will not animate until the page in that tab becomes visible. If an animated GIF is scrolled offscreen even on a foreground page, it will stop animating until it becomes visible again.
>
> Safari’s CPU usage with animated GIFs is very good. (For a while readers of MacNN thought Safari had an “animated GIF problem” because of slowness when typing in forum posts, but that bug actually had to do with the Flash ads at the top and bottom of the page.)

Comment: umm, but the gif should be visible: it's the background-image of a div with z-index: 10000...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's your gif image? I just fired up your code on Safari 4.0.4 under windows with a gif created on http://www.ajaxload.info/ and works flawlessly.

Comment: I tried a gif from ajaxload.info, but I cannot see it :\
I tried both a trasnparent gif and a normal one :\

Comment: This is my/your code, working on said safari.

http://work4bandwidth.com/demos/backroundgif.html
lemme know if it works for you